# Firefox unable to play sound?

Tags: firefox, audio, flash-player

after running Netflix for the first time I am unable to listen to two of my favorite stations: http://www.wgst.com and http://www.cpr.org – although Internet Explorer has no problem playing either of those two radio stations. Firefox has no problem, however, playing Netflix – the sound comes through like a champ.

Any suggestions? (I have downloaded a new Firefox and have downloaded a new Flash player – no difference, the same problem)

Answer (score 3):

Netflix uses [Microsoft Silverlight](https://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/) for its video player. The other two sites mentioned use Adobe Flash Player. Flash Player `11.3` now has its own process (`FlashPlayerPlugin_*.exe`) with individual volume control, so it is possible that it is muted.

To fix this, open the Windows **Volume Mixer** (`sndvol`) and adjust Flash Player's level accordingly:

[image: volume mixer]

Comment: One of the first things I looked at was the mixer: nothing is muted and, again, there is not a problem with sounds on Netflix, nor with Internet Explorer. Just with Mozilla, Chrome, SeaMonkey, and Safari. That is if I open up either of the two URLs above they do not function (that is, the websites function properly but without sound) in anything but Internet Explorer, not my browser of choice. An uninstall/reinstall of Mozilla did not fix the problem, nor did an uninstall/reinstall all of RealPlayer, Flash, Shockwave nor of Silverlight. I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: perhaps one of the things that might give an idea what might or might not be going on: there is no Flash entry on the mixer

Comment: curiouser and curiouser: an uninstall/reinstall of Chrome now operates properly – full sound on the above-mentioned sites.

Comment: Google Chrome uses its own Flash Player, separate from Firefox, Opera, Safari. Internet Explorer also does not share the same Flash Player. I will update my answer later with more details and a possible fix for resetting Flash Player for these two sets of browser plugins.

Comment: "I will update my answer later with more details and a possible fix for resetting Flash Player for these two sets of browser plugins."???????

Answer (score 0):

This might by due to a bug in Flash Player. See this links for additional info:

http://forums.adobe.com/message/4522521

https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3210964